# Android Emulator 23/6.0 wrong keyboard input

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I am trying to use Android Emulator, with a Google API Intel Atom x86_64 avd.

When I try this:

```
emulator64-x86 -avd myavd -qemu -enable-kvm
```

The keyboard input in the Android emulator is incorrect. When I type a key, another key appears inside the emulator, it appears the mapping is incorrect. For example, when I press 'q', the key 'c' appears in the emulator, 'p' is transformed to 'x'.

I do see a warning when starting the emulator:

Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug this?

To get the emulator to work, I also had to do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_DIR/tools/lib64/qt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help if you find out what key map is being used. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#QWERTY-based_layouts_for_Latin_script) a list on wikipedia, but I personally couldn't find anything useful.

Also, in the command line, (I'm assuming you're using android studio) have you tried using `-keyset <file>`? I got it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html), and it looks like it should work by setting the keyset but I haven't tried it. If you're not using Android Studio, maybe there's an equivalent. I hope this helps, good luck.